# @require paths resolving in Stylus

Tags: stylus

Is there any way to avoid the `@require '../../../../xyz` in Stylus? Will Stylus automatically look for the ancestor folders if I only `@require 'xyz` like node.js (with node_modules)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use [--resolve-url](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/executable.html#resolving-relative-urls-inside-imports) option and add your assets folder to paths
Command line:

```
stylus --include <path>
```

Or use `paths` parameter for gulp-stylus or grunt-contrib-stylus